# Android activity flow. Updating activity content

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity called `WorkListingActivity` and it call another activity named `UpdateActivity`. This how i coded the intent at the `WorkListingActivity` class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateActivity.class);
Bundle bundleMsg = new Bundle();
bundleMsg.putCharSequence("ORDER_NUMBER", orderTemp[i]);
//
//PUTTING DATA AND SO ON
//
startActivity(intent);
```

I send some data to the `UpdateActivity` to make some changes. These data retrieve by the `WorkListingActivity` from server database. It retrieve all the data and list it in a form of table. When user click a row. All the data in that particular row will be send to `UpdateActivity`. `UpdateActivity` will make changes to the data and then save it to the server database.

Now that just an introduction. The problem that im having is after the changes have been made where `WorkListingActivity` will be called back. I just add this line

```
UpdateActivity.this.finish();
```

This will bring back the `WorkListingActivity` right? But how to make the table at the `WorkListingActivity` automatically update its content after `UpdateActivity` have been finished? Furthermore, i want the user to be able to go back to the WorkListingActivity by clicking back button. so i cant finish the `WorkListingActivity` during the intent

Comment: use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity

Comment: im sorry. im a beginner in android dev. what does startActivityForResult do? how will it help?

Comment: call the server for retrieving data in onResume() function.

Comment: to know more about startActivityForResult https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use `startActivityForResult(intent)` in your `WorkListingActivity` instead of just `startActivity(intent);`
2. override following method in your WorkListingActivity

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   //update the content in the table and then fetch the data
   //call notifydatasetchanged on your adapter. 
   }
   ```